# Auto check radio button using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have basic HTML form.

This my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5n8837w3)

I want to write a small jQuery to auto check radio button with `*class="st13"` `value="13"*` where have email `root@root.com` and `anna@zzz.com` like this picture.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SZO2.png)

I tried 2 jQuery but not ok. Please help me fix it. Thanks you

```
var emails = [
    'root@root.com',
  'anna@zzz.com'
];
$('input[type="radio"].st13').each(function() {
    var radio = $(this);
  var email = $(this).parent().prev('td').html();
  console.log($.inArray(email, emails));
  if ($.inArray(email, emails) != -1) {
    radio.prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

and

```
$("td").each(function(){var n=$(this).html();(n.indexOf("root@")>-1||n.indexOf("anna@")>-1)&&$(this).next().children("input[class*='st13'][value='13'][type='radio']").prop("checked",!0)});
```

Comment: Your code is working, what is the problem? Did you include jQuery? https://jsfiddle.net/5n8837w3/2/

Comment: I'm sorry, my misstake. Thanks you